# Coyote Timing not working in game with Double Jump. (C#, Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a platformer with a double jump and coyote timing, but the coyote timing doesn't seem to work with the double jump. Whenever the coyote jump is supposed to trigger, the character uses their double jump instead.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && extraJumps > 0 
|| Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && extraJumps > 0
|| Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && extraJumps > 0)
{
    rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
    extraJumps--;
    audioSource.Play();
}
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && extraJumps == 0 && coyoteCounter > 0f 
|| Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && extraJumps == 0 && coyoteCounter > 0f 
|| Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && extraJumps == 0 && coyoteCounter > 0f)
{
    rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
    audioSource.Play();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what "Coyote Timing" is? You might consider reworking your logic to simplify things a bit. `if (jump key pressed) { if (extraJumps > 0) { ... } else { ... } }`

Comment: Coyote Timing is essentially a grace period where you can still jump after falling off of a platform.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)", "[mre]" and their linked pages. We can't run your code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for double jumps before you check for coyote time.
When you check that first block of code, it will always use the double jump before it checks for coyote time.
This should fix your issue:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
    {
        // Check coyote timer before we activate a double jump
        if (coyoteCounter > 0f)
        {
            rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
            audioSource.Play();
        }
        // Now we have run out of coyoteCounter, time to use double jumps
        else if (extraJumps > 0)
        {
            rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
            extraJumps--;
            audioSource.Play();
        }
    }
```

You may also want to make sure that the player can only trigger `coyoteCounter` once ;)